# Print webbrowsercontrol with background colors

Tags: vb.net, browser, printing, background

I am generating the code at runtime and entering it in the webbrowser1.Document for display.

There are some tables with colored cells that I need to print out. By default the webbrowser doesn't print background colors. Is there a way to override it? since I am generating the code via runtime I cannot use images as background.

Also printscreen is not an option because the page is bigger than the size of the webbrowser itself.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: are you trying to use web browser as syntax highlighter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by editing the register at Runtime! edit the register, print, restore the register.. :)